# Suppress output from attr() in function result

Tags: r, attributes

In the source code for `data.frame`, the last three lines of code set the attributes and return the result.

```
    ...
    attr(value, "row.names") <- row.names
    attr(value, "class") <- "data.frame"
    value
}
```

In a function I wrote, the result is a named list created by `lapply`. Before I set any attributes in the function body, result is as follows.

```
> x <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])    
> (g <- grep.dataframe("a|c", x))
# ...    
# $b
#   value row
# 1     a   1
# 2     c   3
> attributes(g)  # I want "list" in here...
# $names
# [1] "a" "b"
```

I'd like "class" to be included in the attributes list, so I add `attr(res, "class") <- "list"` (`res` is the final result) just before `res`. "class" now shows up in the attributes list. However,it also prints out with the result of the function, which I don't want.  I tried wrapping it with `invisible`, but that didn't work.

Why do the manually assigned attributes print with the function result, but are suppressed in a new data frame I create?

```
> (h <- grep.dataframe("a|c", x))
# ...    
# $b
#   value row
# 1     a   1
# 2     c   3

# attr(,"class")  # ...This prints with the result. I don't want that.
# [1] "list"
> attributes(h)   # ...But I want these attributes
# $names
# [1] "a" "b"

# $class
# [1] "list"
```

Comment: You need to add / modify the print method for your class.  For example, study the code for `print.data.frame`

Comment: Is it important that your `data.frame` looses the `data.frame` attribute? Otherwise just use `attr(res, "class") <- c("list", "data.frame")`.

Comment: @shadow, it goes in as a `data.frame`, but a `list` is returned.  It's a list of data frames, if that matters. But the individual list elements in the results are themselves data frames.

Comment: I don't think the fact that your list is created by `lapply` is relevant. Try `res <- list(1); attr(res, "class") <- "list"; res`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you absolutely need a class attribute when apparently lists do not have one by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?class` documentation offers some pointers:

> Many R objects have a class attribute, a character vector giving the names of the classes from which the object inherits. If the object does not have a class attribute, it has an implicit class, "matrix", "array" or the result of mode(x) (except that integer vectors have implicit class "integer"). (Functions oldClass and oldClass<- get and set the attribute, which can also be done directly.)
>
> When a generic function fun is applied to an object with class attribute c("first", "second"), the system searches for a function called fun.first and, if it finds it, applies it to the object. If no such function is found, a function called fun.second is tried. If no class name produces a suitable function, the function fun.default is used (if it exists). If there is no class attribute, the implicit class is tried, then the default method.

From that and running a few simple tests, I gather that:

- a list is one of these *implicit classes*: see `attributes(list(1))`, `typeof(list(1))`
- when `print` is called on a list, it is using `print.default`
- `print.default` prints the attributes of an object

So you could define a `print.list` that will handle your special case:

```
 print.list <- function(x, ...) {
    if (is.list(x)) attr(x, "class") <- NULL
    print.default(x, ...)
 }

res <- list(1)
attr(res, "class") <- "list"
res
# [[1]]
# [1] 1

attributes(res)
# $class
# [1] "list"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a go.  While it's true that an unnamed list has no attributes, a named list like I'm using does have a "names" attribute.  I do find it a bit confusing why a data frame would have a class attribute in its attribute list, but not a list.

Comment: @RichardScriven Because data frames are a special type of list with a class of data.frame.  So they have a class but not all lists do.  What is confusing about that exactly?

Comment: @Dason, Perhaps "confusing" was the wrong word. It's just surprised me I guess, given that the other structures have class attributes

Comment: I'm writing my first package, so still learning about methods, attributes, arguments, etc. There may be a few more posts before I'm through. :)