# Add a silent attribute to an object in R so that it doesn't print to console unless inspected directly?

Tags: r

Is there a way to [set an object's attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547349/5783745) such that the attribute *does not* print to console when the object is called (but which still allows the attribute to be inspected when `attributes()` is called on the object)?

#### Example

E.g. if `x` is given a random attribute

```
x <- 1:5
attr(x, 'some_attribute') <- "value of the attribute"
```

we can inspect the attribute

```
attributes(x)
$some_attribute
[1] "value of the attribute"
```

but the attribute also prints to console when the object is called

```
x
[1]  1  2  3  4  5
attr(,"some_attribute")
[1] "value of the attribute"
```

#### Question

Is there a way to set an attribute so that it doesn't print to console when the object is called?

That is (from the example above) such that `x` prints without the attribute(s) set for it

```
x
[1]  1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: you could define a print method in which the attributes are set to NULL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885870/suppress-output-from-attr-in-function-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `comment` attribute:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/comment.html

```
comment(x) <- "This value won't print."
```